# How to automatically create a hsqldb in embedded mode

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hsqldb

I currently developing a java desktop app using hibernate +hsqldb 
have created an hsqldb database in embedded mode and my hibernate config file is the following

```
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\Users\Desktop\project1\okbadb</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
<event type="create">
</event>

  <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
  </properties>
  </session-factory>
```

The `connection url` is local and depend to my machine
My question is how to create a new database  each time my app is installed (in different machines)
and how can I use a sql script for this purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

Each time the program runs on a different machine, the database is created in the absolute path that you have used.

You can use the `~` at the beginning of a relative path to create a database in a subdirectory of the users home directory. For example `jdbc:hsqldb:file:~\project1\okbadb`

HSQLDB creates a database if it does not already exist. Therefore there is no separate command to create a database.